# Reverse list where indexes are even

Tags: python, list

I would like to reverse a list but only where the indexes are even.
So my goal is that a list that starts like :

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Should look like :

```
B = [5,2,3,4,1]
```

So to check where indexes are even I write :

```
for j in range(0,len(A)):
     if j % 2 == 0:
         print(A[j])        #prints all the values at equal indexes.
```

How would I only reverse A where the above condition is met to for B?
So to explain more , I would like indexes of array A to swap where they are even . Indexes that are even are : 0 , 2 , 4 where the values of A are
1 , 3 , 5 . I want these values to switch to 5,3,1 but indexes that are not even should stay the same.

Is there a quick method like :

```
A[::-1]
```

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: The indexes in an array are `0, 1, 2, 3, ... len(A) - 1`. What do you mean by being equal?

Comment: So where the index of the array mod 2 =0 .
So for list A : index 0 = 1 , index 1 =2 , index 2 = 3 , index 3 = 4 , index 4 = 5.
So index value mod 2 = 0 at : index 0 , index 2 and index 4 . 
I want to reverse all index values that meet the above requirement .
So that index 0 is index 4 and index 2 would stay index 2 since it is in the middle.

Comment: That is called *even* not *equal*.

Comment: My bad I fixed it .

Comment: So you actually want to reverse the array where the indices are odd right, according to what B is?

Comment: `A[::2] = reversed(A[::2])`? @RichardKYu - It's even, indices start at 0.

Comment: Classic I forgot indices start at 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Others like Michael Szczesny have suggested more concise solutions like:

```
A[::2] = reversed(A[::2])
```

already in the comments, but here is one that is more verbose in case it helps you see what is going on.

We'll assume that the list starting out is already sorted.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]


#We isolate the even indices
even_indices = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if i%2==0:
        even_indices.append(A[i])

#We reverse the even indices
even_indices = list(reversed(even_indices))
print(even_indices)

B = []
#We put everything back together, if the index is odd, we use the value from A, if not, we use the value from even_indices, which has been reversed.
for i in range(len(A)):
    if i%2==1:
        B.append(A[i])
    else:
        B.append(even_indices[i//2])


print(B)
```

Output:

```
[5, 3, 1]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```